# CSS calc(), linear equations, and mixing em/px units: Can I multiply ems and pixels to get an em value?

Tags: css

I have a few heading tags that have line-height values that roughly match up with a linear equation: `y = -0.007x + 1.5px`, where `y` is the line-height in ems and `x` is the font-size in pixels. So if font-size is 24px, line-height should be ~1.332em or ~32px.

I thought the calc would look something like this:

```
line-height: calc(-0.007 * 1em + 1.5px);
```

However, this outputs `1.333px` instead of `1.333em`, so it doesn't work.

Is it possible to make this work? I'm not sure what I'm asking, something along the lines of:

- Can I get 1em to be treated as 24px for the purposes of calculation?
- Can I convert 1.333px to 1.333em somehow?
- Can I express what I want in a different way to make it happen?

If it's not possible, why not? What am I missing conceptually?

Comment: *if font-size is 24px, line-height should be ~1.332em*. What about setting `line-height: 1.5`?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan The goal is to set one property for a variety of heading styles. I'm targeting a design that specified 24/32, 28/36, 32/40, 48/56. As the font size gets larger, the line height gets a bit smaller proportionally. So a single fixed value doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As specified, line-height is `calc(-0.007 * 1em + 1.5px)`
And from this equation, first 1em converted `24px`, and after multiplying it with `0.007`, it will become `0.168px`
and subtracting it from 1.5px, ~1.332px.

This can be solved in another way

So you are targeting a design that specified 24/32, 28/36, 32/40, 48/56. *(from comment)*

For this condition, use this following code

```
line-height: calc(1em + 8px);
```

This is as simple as this

Comment: This definitely answers the "Can I express what I want in a different way to make it happen?" question, thanks! I'll hold off on accepting though because I'm still interested in whether or not I can do what I want with a linear equation, if I don't need to here.